# Non Recursive Algorithm to Generate All possible factor combinations of a list of prime factors

Tags: math, combinations, prime-factoring

Say we have factors some list of prime factors such as A, B, C, D multiplied together equal integer n

and want to generate every combination of the factorization non-recursively like

```
[A, B, C, D]
[(A*B), C, D]
[(A*C),B,D]
[(A*D),C,D]
```

.... And

```
[(A*B*C),D]
```

... ect 
until we have generated all possible combinations, duplicate factorings are ok. Main concern is the algorithm speed, because looking to use this for as many prime factors as possible such as 100 prime factors.

Is there a good/efficient algorithm for this, or library, or programing language that will do this. Thanks

Comment: Really 100 prime factors? Have you worked out how many possible combinations that is? (It's *way* too many to enumerate practically.) What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Also: is `[A*B, C*D]` a possible output combination?

Comment: Mark. No I have not worked out how many combinations that is, I know it is a lot, but may be possible using a supercomputer maybe not, but would like to try. The problem is to generate all the combinations of a given list of factors, I'm working for a math researcher to develop this program. Yes [A*B, C*D] is a possible output combination.

Comment: If you have 100 distinct prime factors, then there are 2**100 subsets of those factors. That only covers combinations of the form [product, remaining terms], and you have more than that, since you may have multiple products in your combinations. At that point you're _way_ out of the range of supercomputers (even possible future supersupercomputers), so you may want to think about other ways to solve the underlying problem, whatever that is.

Comment: You make a good point. Maybe then we can only do 50 or 75, but want to push as far we can, and for the problem there is no getting around generating all the combinations, and the more efficient the algorithm the more factors we should be able to do. Edit: Also we dont need to save every combination, so memory is not the issue, just the computing time and speed to generate each combination.

Comment: So if you're talking distinct prime factors, then the number sequence you're interested in is OEIS sequence [A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110), the sequence of Bell numbers, which count [set partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set). The 25th Bell number is 4638590332229999353; if you were to enumerate a billion partitions a second, it would take you around 150 years to enumerate all combinations. So going beyond 25 distinct prime factors is probably not realistic. :-)